What can I do after my iPhone 13 Pro’s camera spontaneously been declared an “Unknown Part?” Never repair or replaced
Craziest thing happened to me a few days ago: I was taking a very simple picture on a table a few days ago when the Camera app seemingly froze with the picture I was taking being displayed but no other controls shown.
I quit the app, launched the Camera again and, yet again, it was showing the same picture I took. But also, suddenly a weird notification message showed up about a non-Apple part. And when I clicked on it showed this utterly baffling message.


”Unknown Part
The camera for this iPhone is not recognized. An Apple Authorized Service Provider can repair or replace the camera to restore full functionality.”

What the heck? I didn’t repair the camera now or ever! The phone is basically 1 month old and purchased as a factory refurb directly from the Apple Store.
I attempted to fix this on my own doing the following:

Restart the phone.
Soft reset. Reset all settings on the phone. A clearing of settings only; kept all media and apps.
Hard reset: Reset the phone from scratch; a hard reset that I had to restore all media and apps from a backup.

Nothing worked! The same @!#?@!-ing “Unknown Part” message shows up from the Settings menu after each step!
What the heck happened and what can I do?
PS: The camera sorta still worked. If I chose “Photo” or “Video” the zoom options quickly flashed from 0.5x, 1x and 3x to simply 2x. And if I went to other options like “Slow Mo” or “Time Lapse” the zoom options showed 0.5x, 1x and 3x. But if I clicked on 0.5x, it would simple bounce over to 1x and never stick. Pinch and zoom barely worked also.

Go to the Apple Store and get the iPhone looked at.
In my case, they did a hardware diagnostic and replaced the camera for free since, while refurbished, since it was still under warranty.
I setup an appointment with my local Apple Store. Explained what happened and what I did to attempt to self-solve the issue.
I explained I work in IT so they were assured that I know what I am talking about also. So after hashing things out, the Apple Store employee asked me to put the device into “Repair Mode” and they then ran diagnostics on the iPhone and lo and behold… The camera itself was showing as defective.
The Apple Store employee explained to me that the “Unknown Part” message is a bit vague and basically means, “The camera is either a non-OEM Apple part or the camera is defective for some reason. Replace it with an OEM part.”
They took the phone and about 90 minutes later, fixed the issue by installing a new camera module. And all is good! Heck, they didn’t even have to wipe the phone in my case to install the camera; small miracles!
Posting this since it seems to be a common issue with iPhone 13 Pro and iPhone 13 Pro Max models. See the following links:

Apple Discussions: “Unknown Part Unable to determine if your iPhone camera is a genuine Apple part.”
Apple Discussions: “camera unknown part”
Reddit: iphone 13 pro max camera unknown part !? purchased from apple never done any repairs, 0.5 camera doesn’t work at all looking for a fix.
Reddit: Camera: Unknown Part (purchased directly from Apple, never been repaired)

These are just the top hits from Google and there are tons more.
The Apple OEM camera module for iPhone 13 Pro models might spontaneously fail; the only solution is to swap out the defective camera module with a new/working camera module. If you live near an official Apple Store and they have the part in stock, the repair should be quick and easy.
